# Overlay map using ggplot2

Tags: r

I am using ggplot2 to plot a matrix, and then I am using geom_text to add some letters in each point. Now, I was wondering if it is possible and how, overlaying a map, since the values represent the European region. This is my try:

```
       library(ggplot2)

       mat1<- melt(vals[,t.lat])   # matrix [long,lati]
       mat2<- melt(names[,t.lat])  # matrix [long,lati]

       p  <-ggplot(mat1, aes(lon,lat, fill=val)) + geom_raster() +
       geom_text(label = mat2$val,na.rm=TRUE,size=3)+
       scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red",na.value="white")
```

The image that I get with this code is:

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible with ggplot2 adding the contour map to define the regions . Any idea about that???

Thanks in advance
Thanks for the comments. I will try to make a reproducible sample (since the original data is too much). The structure would be the same, except that the original matrix have some NA.

```
      library(ggplot2)
      #Coordinates
      lati <- seq(from = 72, to = 34, by =-1) 
      loni <- seq(from=-13,to=34,by=1)

      m1 <- array(runif(length(loni)*length(lati)),dim=c(length(loni),length(lati)))
      m2 <- array(c("A","B"),dim=c(length(loni),length(lati)))

      t.lat  <-c(length(lati):1) #reverse latitude
      mat1<- melt(m1[,t.lat])   # matrix [long,lati]
      mat2<- melt(m2[,t.lat]) 

      names(mat1) <- c("lon","lat","val")
      names(mat2) <- c("lon","lat","val")

      p  <-ggplot(mat1, aes(lon,lat, fill=val)) + geom_raster() +
           geom_text(label = mat2$val,na.rm=TRUE,size=3)+
           scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red",na.value="white")
```

Then, I would like to overlay the area defined by the coordinates , loni and lati, which would be something similar to add a map in background. 
I hope the question is clearer now with the example.

Thanks again.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example, using `dput` to provide the `vals`, `names` and `t.lat` variables. That would let answerers reproduce the problem and test solutions.

Comment: The answer is "yes", it is possible. For more than that, you would need to provide your data and identify the countries covered in you map.

Comment: At the beginning of your question, you talk about "maps" and "European region", as though you want to overlay geographic boundaries. But later you talk about "adding contour map". Which is it? Also know that if you make an edit I don't automatically find out about it unless you ping me with a comment.